# php loop wrapping every 4 results with div and custom classes

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to add some custom classes based on the number of results of each wrapping block.

1. Add the class `last` on the last  of each wrapping block.
2. Count the results of each wrapping block and depending on the results add a custom class, `one-half` `one-third` `one-fourth`

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$array = range(1, 11);

    $i= 0;
    foreach ($array as $val) {
        if ($i%4 == 0) echo '<div class="item">';
        $i++;
?>
    <span class="one-fourth"><?=$val?></span>
<?php       
        if ($i%4 == 0) echo '</div>';
    }
    if ($i%4 != 0) echo '</div>';
?>
```

Output I get:

```
<div class="item"> 
    <span class="one-fourth">1</span>
    <span class="one-fourth">2</span>
    <span class="one-fourth">3</span>
    <span class="one-fourth">4</span>
</div>
<div class="item"> 
    <span class="one-fourth">5</span>
    <span class="one-fourth">6</span>
    <span class="one-fourth">7</span>
    <span class="one-fourth">8</span>
</div>
<div class="item"> 
    <span class="one-fourth">9</span>
    <span class="one-fourth">10</span>
    <span class="one-fourth">11</span>
</div>
```

Output I want:

```
<div class="item"> 
    <span class="one-fourth">1</span>
    <span class="one-fourth">2</span>
    <span class="one-fourth">3</span>
    <span class="one-fourth last">4</span>
</div>
<div class="item"> 
    <span class="one-fourth">5</span>
    <span class="one-fourth">6</span>
    <span class="one-fourth">7</span>
    <span class="one-fourth last">8</span>
</div>
<div class="item"> 
    <span class="one-third">9</span>
    <span class="one-third">10</span>
    <span class="one-third last">11</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably most easily done by splitting the array into chunks and processing each chunk individually in a loop, using the `count` of the chunk to decide which class to add to the spans:

```
$array = range(1, 11);
$chunks = array_chunk($array, 4);

$span_classes = ['', 'one-half', 'one-third', 'one-fourth'];

foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    echo "<div class=\"item\">\n";
    $count = count($chunk);
    $span_class = $span_classes[$count-1];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $last = $i == $count - 1 ? ' last' : '';
        $val = $chunk[$i];
        echo "<span class=\"$span_class$last\">$val</span>\n";
    }
    echo "</div>\n";
}
```

Output:

```
<div class="item">
<span class="one-fourth">1</span>
<span class="one-fourth">2</span>
<span class="one-fourth">3</span>
<span class="one-fourth last">4</span>
</div>
<div class="item">
<span class="one-fourth">5</span>
<span class="one-fourth">6</span>
<span class="one-fourth">7</span>
<span class="one-fourth last">8</span>
</div>
<div class="item">
<span class="one-third">9</span>
<span class="one-third">10</span>
<span class="one-third last">11</span>
</div>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/V24ff)